# Collect Exceptions using background application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exception, event-log

I've this situation:
Main application monitored by a background application.
My background application has to email me if the main application is closed or interrupted, and restore it.

It's working quite well but I want to add a feature:
If the main application throws an unhandled exception I want to collect it in some ways in the background application.

Substantially what I want to know is that: when an exception is throw, Windows saves that "error" somewhere? In the event collector for example?

Thanks

Comment: If there's a crash you should be able to find exception details in Windows Event Viewer ( https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/wes/windows-event-log ) in Application section

Comment: That main application should handled exceptions itself and at least log unhandled exceptions. All stacks have a way of catching unhandled exceptions, eg through `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.